# Как разместить изображения в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вставил изображения, которые соответствуют размерам слайдера, но они всё равно растягиваются. Подскажите, что не так? Заранее спасибо

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 16px;
    
}


* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container,
.select-box,
.media {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}



a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #000000;

}

.tel {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-right: 850px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.pay {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 225px;

}

a.pay:hover {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}


.feedback {

    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;

}

a.feedback:hover {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}

section {
    padding-top: 113px
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

ul,
li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.header-top,
.media {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}



.header-top {
    padding: 4px 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-color: #F6B300;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;

}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro);

body {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #414141;
    font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.select-box {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 20em;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: -39px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 200px;



}

.select,
.label {
    color: #000000;
    font: 400 17px/2em 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 26px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;



}

.select {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height: 40px;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    background: none transparent;
    border: 0 none;
}

.select-box1 {
    background: #F6B300;
}

.label {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.open .label::after {
    content: "▲";
}

.label::after {
    content: "▼";
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 1;
    padding: 1px 20px;
}

.media {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    max-width: 1400px;
    padding-left: 30px;





}

.logo img {

    width: 230px;
    height: 45px;
}

.r-icon {
    width: 100%px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 800px;

}

.r-icon img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
}

.register a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FF0000;
}

.register a:hover {
    text-decoration-line: none;
    
    
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    background-color: #c0392b;
    margin-right: 70px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 50px;
    right: 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 16;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button span,
.button .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;

}

.button span {
    width: 72%;
    line-height: inherit;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button span:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #a53125;
    width: 2px;
    height: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    right: -1px;
}

.button .icon {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 6px;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4);
}

.button .icon .fa {
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.31, -0.105, 0.43, 1.4), height 0.25s ease;
}

.button .icon .fa-remove {
    height: 36px;
}

.button .icon .fa-check {
    display: none;
}

.button.success span,
.button:hover span {
    left: -72%;
    opacity: 0;
}

.button.success .icon,
.button:hover .icon {
    width: 100%;
}

.button.success .icon .fa,
.button:hover .icon .fa {
    font-size: 45px;
}

.button.success {
    background-color: #F6B300;
}

.button.success .icon .fa-remove {
    display: none;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.button:hover .icon .fa-remove {
    height: 46px;
}

.button:active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background: #D10000;
}

.string{
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 1400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.c1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.c-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/catalog.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
}


.catalog {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9px;
    
}

.catalog:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

.b1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-left: 39px;
}

.b-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/gift.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}


.bonus {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.bonus:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

.a1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-left: 39px;
}

.a-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/percent.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
}


.stocks {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.stocks:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

.m1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-left: 39px;
}

.m-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/shop.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}


.shops {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.shops:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

.d1{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    margin-left: 39px;
}

.d-icon {
    background-image: url('../img/delivery.svg');
    background-size: contain;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}


.delivery {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 9px;
}

.delivery:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-underline-position: under;
    margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

.carousel {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel__controls,
.carousel__activator {
  display: none;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(2) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(3) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(3):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(4) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(4):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__track {
  transform: translateX(-400%);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__controls:nth-of-type(5) {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__activator:nth-of-type(5):checked ~ .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fafafa;
  opacity: 0.35;
  outline: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}
.carousel__control:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__control--backward {
  left: 10px;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.carousel__control--forward {
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.carousel__indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.carousel__indicator {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.35;
  margin: 0 2.5px 0 2.5px;
}
.carousel__indicator:hover {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.carousel__track {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: translateX(200%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: translateX(300%);
}
.carousel__track .carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  transform: translateX(400%);
}
.carousel--scale .carousel__slide {
  transform: scale(0);
}
.carousel__slide {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
/**
  * Theming
*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;

}
.my-carousel {
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.carousel__slide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicator {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
}

.carousel__indicator {
  background-color: #D10000;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(1),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url("../img/142BBD273D53DA3FA54A3AE9D493F64C_1618562766589.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(2),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url("../img/astykzhan_176012651_311136380670048_2190586481430973455_n.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(3),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url("../img/astykzhan_188316891_2963519800591105_8369683926835455518_n.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(4),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url("../img/astykzhan_193058876_314263970138682_1411469765474473484_n.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.carousel__slide:nth-of-type(5),
.carousel--thumb .carousel__indicators .carousel__indicator:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url("../img/astykzhankostanay_186783740_291232569330232_4284322746624849312_n.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Астыкжан</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,300&family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="tel:+77479009999" class="tel"> +7 747 900 99 99 </a>
                <a href="#" class="pay"> Оплата </a>
                <a href="#" class="feedback">Обратная связь</a>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <label for="select-box1" class="label select-box1"><span class="label-desc">Ваш город</span> </label>
                    <select id="select-box1" class="select">
                        <option value="Choice 1">Нур-Султан</option>
                        <option value="Choice 2">Костанай</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="/index.html">
                <img src="img/ex.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="r-icon">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/user.png">
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="register">
            <a href="#"> Вход/Регистрация
            </a>
            </div>
            <a class="button" href="#">
    <span>Корзина</span>
    <div class="icon">
    <img src="img/cart.png">
        <i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
    </div>
    <script>(function() {
  var removeSuccess;

  removeSuccess = function() {
    return $('.button').removeClass('success');
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {
    return $('.button').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass('success');
      return setTimeout(removeSuccess, 3000);
    });
  });

}).call(this);</script>
</a>         
    </div>
    <script>
        $("select").on("click", function() {
            $(this).parent(".select-box").toggleClass("open");
        });
        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            var container = $(".select-box");

            if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                container.removeClass("open");
            }
        });


        $("select").on("change", function() {

            var selection = $(this).find("option:selected").text(),
                labelFor = $(this).attr("id"),
                label = $("[for='" + labelFor + "']");

            label.find(".label-desc").html(selection);

        });

    </script>
    <div class="navbar">
       <div class="string">
        <a href="#" class="c1">
            <div class="c-icon"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="catalog">Каталог</span>
            </div>
        </a>
          <a href="#" class="b1">
            <div class="b-icon"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="bonus">Бонусы</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="a1">
            <div class="a-icon"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="stocks">Акции</span>
            </div>
        </a>
         <a href="#" class="m1">
            <div class="m-icon"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="shops">Магазины</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="d1">
            <div class="d-icon"></div>
            <div class="menu">
                <span class="delivery">Доставка</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel my-carousel carousel--translate">
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="F" checked="checked"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="G"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="H"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="I"/>
    <input class="carousel__activator" type="radio" name="carousel" id="J"/>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="J"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="G"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="H"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="I"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="J"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__controls">
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--backward" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__control carousel__control--forward" for="F"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__track">
      <li class="carousel__slide">
     
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
       
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
       
      </li>
      <li class="carousel__slide">
        
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel__indicators">
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="F"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="G"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="H"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="I"></label>
      <label class="carousel__indicator" for="J"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь min-width, max-width для слайдов. flexbox по умолчанию пытается всё впихнуть.